# How to export PGP key (in clear text?)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, key, private, pgp

I created a set of PGP keys in Kleopatra using GPG4Win. I want to use my private and public keys to encrypt and decrypt emails with this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailvelope/kajibbejlbohfaggdiogboambcijhkke
I imported the public key fine, but it seems that the extension also needs the private key. I am wondering how to export the private key (in plain text I guess) so that I can use it in the extension. I can't believe I have been unable to find a solution for this on my own, so any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic. Go to superuser.

Comment: Have you tried this? When choosing "export secret certificate," check "ASCII armor". See page 49 here: http://wald.intevation.org/frs/download.php/1385/gpg4win-compendium-en-3.0.0.pdf